# What's the cause of this NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following code:

```
Cms::Page.class_eval do
  def self.fetch_by_slug(slug)
    Rails.cache.fetch("cms_page_#{slug}") { Cms::Page.find_by_slug(slug) }
  end
end
```

in `config/initializers/cms_mp.rb`

The thing is, I have a call to `fetch_by_slug` in my layout file, and thus, it's called for each request. In development mode, if I do something that triggers a reload of the classes, I receive the error message `undefined method fetch_by_slug for #<Class:0xbff20e8>`, and the only fix is to restart the rails devel server.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that initializers are loaded only on server bootup. I your Cms::Page is reloaded latter then the added method i gone. You should consider to put this code not in initializer but somwere where it will be reloaded with dependent classes.